# Elasticsearch: how to group by a field that is not in the query?

Tags: group-by, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch:
pseudocode:`select all docs that have fieldName=value group by Id`
How can I transfer this to elasticsearch

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to get documents applying filter and grouping by Id.

Here is sample query, (like smart translation of your sql) is

```
POST index/type/_search 
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "fieldname": "vlaue"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "groupById": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "Id",
            "size": 100
         },
         "aggs": {
            "select-all-query": {
               "top_hits": {
                  "size": 100
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Change size parameters to control, how many documents are needed.

References

[Top Hits aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

[Terms aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

Hope this helps!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_aggregations.html).

For example sake, this query groups by city, after filtering on documents having field "fieldName" that contain "value" :

```
GET /{index}/{type}/_search
{
   "aggs":{
       "filter_by_fieldname":{
           "filter":{
            "term":{
                "fieldName":"value"           
             }
           },
           "aggs":{
                "group_by_city": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "city"
                    }
                }                   
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Be aware that defaults settings make that only top 10 cities will be returned (default size), but you can tune that.

Comment: this returns the aggregation, but they are not related to the query above. I need stored in aggs only those ids that match my query

Comment: @Roxana: sorry, I have edited the answer : you have to use a filter aggregation